# Can someone tell me which Quran/Mushaf is it?

Tags: quran, mushaf

[image]

I was watching a  documentary on Yemen, more specifically in Hadramawt, Tarim and I came across this Mushaf. I love it so much. But I do not know which muahaf is it and where to buy it. I would appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

There have been thousands of publishers over the years who have printed the Quran in different styles, it is very unlikely that you will find someone who will be familiar with this particular one, maybe even the publisher no longer exists. If you want something similar ask for a Quran with extra large print. It will likely come divided into multiple volumes or Juz like the one in the photograph.